# Why is my implementation of Conway's game of Life not giving me the right results?

Tags: javascript, html

I have just written this implementation of [Conway's game of Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life) and I am not getting the results expected for this program. I have read through all of the documentation I thought I my code was accurate and I can't see what's wrong. I was wondering if anyone would be willing to read my code and explain what it is I'm doing wrong.

Here is my code:

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById('mainCanv');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

let tileWidth = 10;
let tileHeight = 10;
let map = createMultiArray(100,100);
let next = createMultiArray(100,100);
let alive = 0;;
console.table(map)
function main(){
 for(let i = 0; i < map.length; i++){
  for(let j = 0; j < map[i].length; j++){
   if(i>0&&i<map.length-1&&j>0&&j<map.length-1){
    if(checkCells(map,j,i) > 3 && map[i][j] == 1){
     next[i][j] = 0;
    }
    else if(checkCells(map,j,i) < 2 && map[i][j] == 1){
     next[i][j] = 0;
    }
    else if(checkCells(map,j,i) == 2 || checkCells(map,j,i) == 3){
     next[i][j] = 1;
    }
    else if(checkCells(map,j,i) == 3 && map[i][j] == 0){
     next[i][j] = 1;
    }

   }
  }
 } 
 map = next;
 drawMap(map);


}
randomPlacement(map);

function createMultiArray(rows,cols){
 let arr = [];
 for(let i = 0; i < rows; i++){
  arr[i] = [];
  for(let j = 0; j < cols; j++){
   arr[i][j] = 0;
  }
 }
 return arr;
}

function randomPlacement(map){
 let i = 0;
 for(let i = 0; i < map.length; i++){
  for(let j = 0; j < map[i].length; j++){
   map[i][j] = Math.floor(Math.random()*2);
  }
 }
}

function checkCells(map,x,y){
 aliveCells = map[x][y+1]+
    map[x][y-1]+
    map[x+1][y]+
    map[x-1][y]+
    map[x+1][y+1]+
    map[x-1][y-1]+
    map[x+1][y-1]+
    map[x-1][y+1];
 return aliveCells;
}
function drawMap(map){
 for(let i = 0; i < map.length; i++){
  for(let j = 0; j < map[i].length; j++){
   ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
   if(map[i][j] == 1){
    ctx.fillStyle = 'black'
   }
   ctx.fillRect(i*tileWidth,j*tileHeight,tileWidth,tileHeight);
   ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
   ctx.strokeRect(i*tileWidth,j*tileHeight,tileWidth,tileHeight);
  }
 }
}
setInterval(main,50)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Life</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<canvas id="mainCanv"  width="1000" height="1000" style="background-color:grey"></canvas>
</center>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Life.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

When thing go wrong, break it down to manageable churk, and trace sequentially, Here is what I do:

- Reduce the matrix size to 10x10;
- Set the internal to long enough so that a screen capture for each sequence can be taken.

Here are the screen captures of two sequences of the evolution. As you can see that your algorithm for the life is not correct.

#### Sequence 1

[image: Sequence 1]

#### Sequence 2

[image: Sequence 2]